# putting Navicat files in git?

Tags: mariadb, version-control

I'm looking at switching from MySQL Workbench to Navicat because we're using MariaDB and the incompatibilities are starting to annoy me.

I'm working through the issues of getting Navicat to run on Centos under WINE but assume I will succeed **(edit: this failed. The "linux" version requires WINE. Navicat will sort of run with a bit of hacking, but critical features rely on MS-Windows/WINE)**

How do I get Navicat to work with git (or any other source code control)? Workbench is sufficiently primitive that file changes either get picked up automatically or completely ignored (almost always a dialog "file on disk has changed, reload?")

Specific problems:

1. when adding new query files Navicat only seems to rescan the folder when I add a new query. Is there a smart way to do that? *(edit: no. You can manually refresh one file at a time by right clicking)*
2. model and query files are buried deep in the WINE tree. Can I relocate them or or symlinks work? I'd rather keep all the DB-related code in one repo, rather than having a special Navicat repo. *(edit: yes, but the explanation of how to do so is lengthy)*
3. is there a way to merge a model file if more than one person has changed it? Workbench can't do this but I'd really like the feature. *(edit: no, never. Merge the schema SQL files instead)*

Also, bonus question: can we make multiple edits using Navicat other than repeated use of the GUI? If I want to change (say) a bunch of columns from VARCHAR(255) to CHAR(20) I'd normally script that in SQL but Navicat models don't do reverse engineering, only "delete the table from the model then re-import it" so there doesn't seem to be a non-tedious way to do that. *(edit: no, but they might look at it in the future)*

---

Final edit: I used the [Navicat forums and the team were very helpful](https://community.navicat.com/forum/navicat-sales-and-feedback/navicat-pre-sales-questions/2771-mariadb-edition-on-centos-7), but fundamentally Navicat is Windows software and the 64-bit purists behind Centos will never support WINE. For most Linux users this is not a problem, but I work with Centos enthusiasts and have long since lost the argument about which distro to use.

Answer (score -1):

To the 1st question, you can sync it in different ways with a remote database/folder, when you are managing the database with Navicat, just right-click in your current connection and press "refresh", so you will be updated with the server changes. You also can do it with a programmed task.

Another matter is, why would you want to run navicat from wine when it has a native linux version? (I hope that answers the 2nd question)

For the 3rd question note that Navicat has an internal utility to sync data between servers, so you don't need git at all, or at most, you can automate the structure exportation and then sync it with a git repository (in form of a .sql file)

IMHO you need to review your concepts about mariadb and navicat, both are quite flexible and offer several ways to do such things you propose, like sync the data and they also allow to insert git in the workflow, just review your strategy and try to apply some new perspective with the available features.

Comment: The "native linux version" pops up a "Gecko for WINE not found" dialog then fails to run. Sure, it might be native Linux, but it's the special sort of native linux that requires WINE. Also, whatever sync tool we use has to be able to sync and version all project source code, so unless Navicat can also replace git, it needs to work with git. Your comment that we need to review what we're doing... I thought that was what I was doing.

Comment: Sorry for not being useful for solving your problem, I think I misunderstood some of your doubts. Maybe try with Navicat from a Windows VM inside centos?